# How to filter a heatmap layer with QGIS Atlas?

Tags: qgis, heat-map, atlas

I have a dataset with student route node collections from 20 different schools that I want to drive heatmap atlas pages with.

Can the heatmap layer in QGIS have a filter applied, either based on the atlas feature, or a spatial intersect?

I haven't seen anything in QGIS 2.18 or 3.0 that might allow this, but perhaps there is a method I haven't found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method assumes that each school has a unique number, which is a field in the attribute table of the student route node layer, and the atlas coverage layer. You can substitute a field such as school name, as long as both of those layers have the same values for that field.

**Create a virtual layer of student route nodes for each school.**

```
Layer Menu > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer
```

Use this query, substituting the names of your school nodes layer and schoolnumber field.

```
SELECT * FROM student_route_nodes WHERE schoolnumber = 1
```

Give each virtual layer a unique name so you can tell them apart.
[image]

Repeat until you have one virtual layer for each school.

**Copy heat map styling from original layer (student route node collections) to virtual layers.**

Right click on original layer name in layer panel > Style > Copy Style

Select all virtual layers in layer panel. Right click > Paste Style

[image]

**Set visibility of each virtual layer based on atlas page**

**In QGIS 3.0,** use data-defined settings for "Enable Layer" option, with this equation:

```
"schoolnumber" =  attribute( @atlas_feature , 'schoolnumber')
```

**In QGIS 2.18 and earlier**, "Enable layer" setting doesn't exist. Instead you can control layer visibility in the print composer using map themes (item properties > layers > follow map theme). [image]

- Set up a visibility preset for each virtual layer (Layers panel > Manage visibility > add preset). Name each visibility preset with its corresponding schoolnumber value.
- Set up data-defined map theme setting using this expression

  attribute( @atlas_feature , 'schoolnumber')

Comment: Interesting - let me try this and report back. Thanks!!